# Flask-admin ModelView insert ForeignKey data automatically

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-login, flask-admin

I make a tuition payment app using **Flask** and using **Flask-admin** to managing the payment.

I have a `Parent` table, and a `User` table which is I use for school admin.

What I want is, when I added a data to table `User`, I want to get the current ID that I recently added and insert it automatically to `Parent` table

So far, I have made my ModelView like this

```
class UserModelView(sqla.ModelView):

    def create_model(self, form):
        parent = Parent()
        form.populate_obj(parent)

        parent.id = 36      # this is the hardcore ID, want I want is to get the current ID that I recently added

        self.session.add(parent)
        self.session.commit()

        return True
```

So, how to do that..?, any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Not sure if I understand what you mean... Normally, sql keeps track of ids automatically, I wouldn't recommend hardcoding ids. If a specific record exists in parent table, you can make this parent field visible on your create/edit forms of the User modelview in flask admin. Where do things go wrong in your use case?

Comment: Could you add your `User` and `Parent` class definitions? The answer may depend on how ids are generated for the objects of these classes and what is the relationship between them.